# How do domes in lunar impact melts develop, and might they be hollow?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science

On the floors of young craters of the Moon, smoothly rounded domes are visible in some spots. [Lalande crater](http://bit.ly/1mmfRZJ) has 4 of them, each around 200 m across.

[image: domes on floor of Lalande crater]

[image: Lalande crater floor in the evening]

[Here are](http://bit.ly/1kwXYFq) less regular ones on the floor of Copernicus crater. The most pronounced one, in the middle, is 500 m across.

[image: domes on floor of Copernicus crater]

The ones in Lalande in particular are quite round and regular, and make me think of bubbles on the surface of a thick liquid. I have looked for material on such domes without luck. I asked [Paul Spudis](http://www.spudislunarresources.com/) if they could be hollow when he appeared on a recent [Space Show episode](http://www.thespaceshow.com/show/11-dec-2015/broadcast-2602) , and he said yes. (Relevant portion starts at 36:45, with a discussion of impact melts, and then gets into the domes.) He indicated we can't know but it is possible. I wish I'd followed up with more questions, but I thought I'd be taking too much time away from other people with questions, and left it. I won't make that mistake again.

Can anything more specific be said about such domes, for instance based on similar dome morphology on the Earth or other bodies? If they are hollow, would it be the case of a hollow disk at the top of them, or a whole spherical bubble deep inside? If they are solid, then what would be the nature of their development?

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this?

Comment: @called2voyage No, i haven't. I updated a broken link to the show where it was discussed. Since it seems there isn't a way to get a concrete answer because not enough is known, I let it go. IIRC, Spudis said another possibility is the domes are due to a lighter molten material welling up under a skin of hardened material, which could mean they are solid.

Comment: Ok, I considered putting a bounty on this, but it sounds like it's pretty unanswerable for the time being.

Comment: @called2voyage I found the part of the interview where he talked about it and put the timestamp in the question. He didn't get into alternate explanations on the show. I emailed him about it after that and he was kind enough to respond. That was when he mentioned he actually doubted there were voids. Perhaps he'd thought about it more later. What he said is that they could be mounds of ejecta that seem rounded because of how molten material only partly drained from them. Perhaps I heard the thinner liquid hypothesis elsewhere.

Comment: Terrestrial meteorite impact craters get such central features too, and should be more accessible; maybe that would be worth researching?

Comment: @SF. maybe. I know so little about it, it's hard to know how to search. Simple googles don't get anywhere. Note that these structures can be anywhere on the surface of where the impact melt was, they aren't restricted to the central peaks.

Comment: @kimholder: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ maybe? Or at least they could direct you to people interested in meteorites and their craters? (I know there's a fairly good community of meteorite-seekers)

Comment: @SF. I could revisit the matter and inquire there. My feeling is it would be at best a very unusual formation in an Earth crater, otherwise it would get mentioned enough to show up on Google. And the whole process is so different on Earth, i wouldn't consider the case here any clear indication of what happens on another body anyhow. I think if someone as well versed as Paul Spudis really isn't sure, that also shows it's not a known phenomenon on Earth either. His background is geology. I took a stab at it, and now i have neither the time or training to follow up. Such is life.

Comment: There’s been some detailed work on a few specific domes: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f177/14b7b4914f17396861b99f72a6865f911d39.pdf

Comment: @BobJacobsen Ah, yes. But those are quite different. Haven't read about them in a while, but as i recall, they are very large and shallow structures on the open maria. These domes only occur in impact melts, and are only visible (or perhaps only exist) on the floors of young craters.

Comment: @Conelisinspace it certainly could. A mission like that to the Moon would produce a lot of interesting data. I hope we don't have to wait long for such survey missions to launch.